# IntelliJ Java code snippets shortcut list

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-snippets

New to Java and coming from a C# background I'm used for example in Rider to type "prop" followed by a tabulation and it generates for me a property with a get and a set.

I know it's possible to do the same in IntelliJ for example "sout" followed by tabulation generates "System.out.println" but I'm wondering is there a list out there of all the shortcuts available? For instance I'm looking for a shortcut to declare methods in an interface.

Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 5):

The following shortcuts are available in IntelliJ IDEA:

- **psvm or main** - `public static void main`
- **sout** - `System.out.println();`
- **souf** - `System.out.printf("");`
- **psfs** - `public static final String`
- **fori** - `for (int i = 0; i < ; i++) { }`
- **ifn** - `if (var == null) { }`
- **inn** - `if (var != null) { }`
- **St** - `String`
- **thr** - `throw new`

**You can find more in settings (CTRL + ALT + S) > Editor > Live Templates**. Here you have a lot of sections, including a section with Java, where you can find these and many other shortcuts. You can also add your own shortcut using the **Add** button on the top right, or remove one.

Example:
[image]

*Note: This also works in Android Studio.*